# Visual C++ redistributables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

For using Visual C++ redistributables do I need Microsoft Visual Studio License is mandatory ?
Because of various kind of applications are installing various type Visual C++ redistributables for their proper execution.

In this circumstance do I really need Visual Studio License to avoid any legal compliance from Microsoft?

Kindly clarify.
Thanks,
Ram.

Comment: To redistribute anything copyrighted you need a license. Often it's easy to get such a license - eg. it's included when you buy Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Source [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx)

> When you deploy an application, you must also deploy the files that are required to support it. If any of these files are provided by Microsoft, check whether you are permitted to redistribute them. **To review the Microsoft Software License Terms, see License.htm in the directory where Visual Studio is installed, or on the Visual Studio installation media.**

See also [Is redistribution of the C++ 2008 Redistributable Package forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616207/is-redistribution-of-the-c-2008-redistributable-package-forbidden) and [Can Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package be freely redistributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643760/can-microsoft-visual-c-2008-redistributable-package-be-freely-redistributed)

**Disclaimer**

I am not a lawyer.